# copyWithZone returns an object of super class

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a class hierarchy like this:

- `ClassA` inherits from `NSObject`
- `ClassB` inherits from `ClassA`
- `ClassA` implements `copyWithZone:` like this:

implementation:

```
-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    ClassA *clone = [[ClassA allocWithZone:zone] init];
    // other statements
    return clone;
}
```

`ClassB` implementions the same method like this

```
-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    ClassB *clone = [super copyWithZone:zone];
    // other statements
    return clone;
}
```

`ClassC` has a property like this:

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) ClassA *classA;
```

so, when I do something like this:

```
 ClassB *classBPtr = [[ClassB alloc] init];
 ClassC *classCPtr = [[ClassC alloc] init];
 [classCPtr setClassA:classBPtr];
 // other code
```

somehow the the `classA` property of `ClassC` never realizes that `classA` pointer actually points to an instance of `ClassB`. hence if I call a method on `classA`, it would only call the base class's implementation (the one in `ClassA`) instead of the derived class implementation in `ClassB`

any ideas where I might have messed it up?

Comment: please note that it works fine with `retain` attribute in property declaration, goes crazy only when attribute is `copy`. so that's why I think it's `copyWithZone:` who is the culprit.

Comment: Why not just `ClassB *clone = [[ClassB allocWithZone:zone] init];` ?

Comment: actually the above example is a simplified version of the actual problem. what is called `ClassC` in the above example is a manager class that contains objects of a number of subclasses of `ClassA` and it gets populated through reflection. Hence, it is easier for it to just receive a pointer to `ClassA`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try changing

```
ClassA *clone = [[ClassA allocWithZone:zone] init];
```

to

```
ClassA *clone = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] init];
```

Comment: works well. but can anyone tell me what is the difference between ClassA and [self class] here ?

Comment: You can't assume that this method is being called by an instance of `ClassA` - if I have an instance of `ClassB` and I call `copy` on it, I don't want an instance of `ClassA` to come out, I want an instance of `ClassB`. Using `[self class]` gives you the correct class to use i.e. if I call `copy` on an instance of `ClassB` then `[self class]` gives `ClassB`, which means the line becomes `[[Class B allocWithZone:zone] init];`.

Answer (score 2):

```
ClassA

-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
   ClassA *copyObject = NSCopyObject(self, 0, zone);
   //copy ClassA members here

  return copyObject;
}

ClassB

-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
   ClassB *copyObject = [super copyWithZone:zone];
   //copy ClassB members here

  return copyObject;
}
```